# Add columns based on last observation of the same individual

Tags: r, data.table

I have here some artificial data. It can be imagined these are visits by individual humans.

```
n <- 10e4
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id    = sample(1:(n/4), n, replace = TRUE),
                 date  = as.Date("1982-03-03") + 
                           sample(1:900, n, replace = TRUE),
                 score = runif(n, 0, 10),
                 happy = sample(c("Yes", "No"), n, replace = TRUE))
head(df, 4)
     id       date    score happy
1  6638 1983-11-24 7.856568   Yes
2  9304 1983-11-25 5.254272    No
3 14322 1982-12-10 6.525329   Yes
4 22706 1983-07-14 7.551247    No
```

What I would like to do, is add three columns. `Date of most recent visit` (that is t-1), `Score of last visit`, and `Is happy at most recent visit?`.

The end goal is to see if `Score of most recent visit` can predict happiness status in current visit controlling for `Is happy at most recent visit?` and how close in time the two visits are.

Below is what I have started: convert to `data.table` and rank the visits.

```
setDT(df)[, date := as.IDate(date)]
df[order(date), visit.n := 1:.N, by=id]
head(df, 4)
      id       date    score happy visit.n
1:  6638 1983-11-24 7.856568   Yes       5
2:  9304 1983-11-25 5.254272    No       4
3: 14322 1982-12-10 6.525329   Yes       2
4: 22706 1983-07-14 7.551247    No       4
```

Example of desired output:

```
      id       date    score happy visit.n  last.date last.score last.happy
1:  6638 1983-11-24 7.856568   Yes       5 1983-10-29   8.417868        Yes
2:  9304 1983-11-25 5.254272    No       4 1983-09-04   1.290718         No
3: 14322 1982-12-10 6.525329   Yes       2 1982-08-18   3.546896         No
4: 22706 1983-07-14 7.551247    No       4 1983-04-20   8.560386         No
```

Comment: `cols = c("date", "score", "happy"); df[order(date), sprintf("last.%s", cols) := shift(.SD), by=id, .SDcols = cols]` Going to see if I can find a dupe.

Comment: Bravo @Frank. The problem seems solved. While the two answers below misunderstood my intention (probably my fault).

Comment: You could use `.SDcols=date:happy` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood too until your last edit. Always best to show desired output.

Comment: @lmo Yeah, but gotta construct the new var names somehow, so might as well do it this way.

Comment: Thanks @lmo :) `sprintf` vs `paste0` is mostly just aesthetic, so I can more clearly get an idea of what the end result will look like.

Comment: Also leading and trailing 0s and other nice formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is lacking some key details, but if I'm understanding you correctly, it should be possible to do this with *dplyr*:

```
library(dplyr)

new.df <- group_by(df, id) %>%
          mutate(
                 last.visit = max(date),
                 last.score = unique(score[date == max(date)]),
                 last.happy = unique(happy[date == max(date)])
                )
```

This groups `df` by "id", and finds the maximum (i.e., last) date, and the corresponding scores and happiness flags for each id. Note that it relies on the "date" column being formatted as proper `Date`s.

## Edit: a version similar to the DataTable answer

```
new.df <- group_by(df, id) %>%
    arrange(date) %>% 
    mutate(
        last.visit = date[n()],
        last.score = score[n()],
        last.happy = happy[n()]
    )
```

Comment: You are right, key details were (still are?) unclear. Last is ambiguous word so I changed it to "most recent". What you did is unfortunately not what I was aiming at.

Comment: Using `max` should return only the most recent date per id.

Comment: I want to predict happiness status at visit "v" by information from "v-1". Your code gives me an error msg: `Error: incompatible size (2), expecting 4 (the group size) or 1`

Comment: Based on the error, I suspect that it is possible for one id to have multiple visits on the same date. I have modified the code to account for this, using `unique` to ensure that only 1 value is returned.